# repos with proxy working together with repos without it

Tags: proxy, centos, redhat

I'm working with Red Hat/Centos linux, in one company that have the owns repositories (for secury issues) and i had the need of install others package that arent in this repos, so i made some configuration in:

/etc/yum.repo (The configuration about proxy)

```
proxy=server
proxy_username=myuser
proxy_password=mypsw
```

/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date (the configuration about the proxy)

```
enableProxy=1
httpProxy=server
```

/root/.bash_profile

```
export http_proxy="server:port"
```

And console : `export http_proxy=http://myuser:mypsw@server:port`

Change the x.repo (example remi.repo) with the proxy=server:port configuration

After this i use lynx to make one connection, and enter the LOGIN PASSWORD for the proxy server, and after all that is went i can get the package from the x.repo (for 15 min), but the company repos doesn't work.

So the question:

- is possible to have the company repo and the others repo working together?
- If is possible to config the proxy for not doing the lynx connection?
- And if the answer is yes, how to do it, because if not i have to try to install the package A from repo R (remi), but this one have some dependency of repo C (company) i have quit out the proxy config, install the dependecy from C, put the proxy again and install the package A, this was one week of doing this for install some easy thing (5 min max if any proxy is in place)

Comment: What file did you add the proxy information to exactly? You probably only want to do that in the repo files for the repos that need it. Also you can, if you want, put the proxy credential information in the yum or repo files too.

Comment: @EtanReisner i put some information the proxy conf

Comment: So I don't know anything about up2date or RHN so I can't say anything about that unfortunately but if the proxy will not allow you access to every repository then you don't want that configuration in `yum.conf` and instead you want to add it to the `.repo` files for the repositories that need it. Those exact lines are valid in `.repo` files as well.